# Behaviour of bitwise AND and logical AND along with equality operator in Python 3

Tags: python, bitwise-and, logical-and

So I understand bitwise AND is not always safe to use especially if the operands are going to numbers. But am trying to understand what is that tiny subtle reason behind this statement returns to False.

`1110010110001000 == 1110010110001000 & 1 == 1 & 1000001000001101 == 1000001000001101 & 1 == 1` --> False

however when I use logical AND operator it returns True which is fairly verbose and clear but trying to understand why the first statement returns False.

and `1110010110001000 == 1110010110001000 and 1 == 1 and 1000001000001101 == 1000001000001101 and 1 == 1` --> True

PS: wasn't able to find any similar QA in my search.

Comment: `1110010110001000 & 1` is zero.

Comment: What exactly are you *asking*? It should be clear that two different operators may return different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` has higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`.

So this:

```
1110010110001000 == 1110010110001000 & 1 == 1 & 1000001000001101 == 1000001000001101 & 1 == 1
```

means

```
1110010110001000 == (1110010110001000 & 1) == (1 & 1000001000001101) == (1000001000001101 & 1) == 1
```

which means

```
1110010110001000 == 0 == 1 == 1 == 1
```

which means (due to [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons))

```
(1110010110001000 == 0) and (0 == 1) and (1 == 1) and (1 == 1)
```

which is false.

In summary, don't use `&` to mean logical `and`.

Comment: Clear and precise. Thank you @khelwood!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), bitwise and `&` binds stronger than `==` which in turn binds stronger than logical `and`. Hence your code reads as follows:

```py
1110010110001000 == (1110010110001000 & 1) == (1 & 1000001000001101) == (1000001000001101 & 1) == 1
(1110010110001000 == 1110010110001000) and (1 == 1) and (1000001000001101 == 1000001000001101) and (1 == 1)
```

Comment: yeah makes sense now, thanks a lot @a_guest